# What is the shortcut to navigate the cursor to next/previous function block in jetbrains

Tags: shortcuts

In jetbrains, whats the shortcut to navigate the cursor to next/previous function block?

Answer (score 0):

Per default it is `Alt + Down` or `Alt + Up`: [Browse through methods](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#method_navigation)
You can of cource change it in the settings.